# How can I call a shell command from within a pl/pgsql function?

Tags: postgresql, shell, postgresql-8.3

I would like to do something like this, but it doesn't work...

```
CREATE FUNCTION kill(integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    pid ALIAS FOR $2;
BEGIN
    -- Do some stuff here...

    return kill TERM, pid;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**Postgresql 8.3**

**UPGRADING is not an option, sorry...**

Comment: For others landing on this page who *are* using PostgreSQL 9.3 or above, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128254/104401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in PL/PgSQL, but you can in most of the other PLs:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION signal(signum integer, pid integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
return kill $_[0], $_[1];
$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

or use PL/Python if you prefer. Or even PL/TCL.

Alternately, write a simple C extension to expose the `kill` function to SQL. It'll be quite trivial to adapt the examples in the documentation for the purpose.

Comment: Do you need super user access to run the code in your answer ?

Comment: @Alex Of course. If there was any built-in way to signal a process without having superuser access that'd be monsterous security hole. If you want to *add* that in your database you can make the function `SECURITY DEFINER`, `REVOKE` access to it from `PUBLIC`, and `GRANT` rights to only the user(s) or role(s) you want to be able to send signals.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to kill? A query or a backend? If only a query, [pg_cancel_backend()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-admin.html) existed in Postgresql 8.3. If you really need to execute a shell command, you'll need to use one of the "untrusted" procedural languages like plperlu or plpythonu etc. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plperl-trusted.html for more details.

Comment: `pg_terminate_backend` didn't, though, and that's probably what they really want.